# How to restrict certain users from editing all attributes of an object using PUT with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

When using Spring Data Rest is there a way to let certain users only edit part of an entity using a PUT request?

Taking this item as an example:

```
{
    "name": "Item1",
    "description": "Description",
    "creator": "User1"
}
```

What's the best way to let the creator of the item edit the whole item using a PUT request while restricting other users to only edit the "description" field?

I have tried using a custom validator and an event handler without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried REST Repository events?
As in @HandleBeforeSave events and such?

Comment: Yes, problem is that the item that is passed into the handler has already been changed to be the one passed in via the PUT request.

Comment: And is it possible handle the change in the database layer (e.g. if using mysql setting updateable = false)?

Comment: I don't think so. If I set updateable to false for the 'name' and 'creator' columns, the creator too will not be able to edit the fields anymore, right?

Comment: Of course, the restrictions are put on only on fields that are not supposed to be changed (description in this case). Other fields are left as-is

Comment: All users should be able to edit the description field while the name and creator fields should only be edited by the creator himself. What you are suggesting would make the description field non editable which is not what I want when I understood you correctly.

Comment: Ok, now I get it... Then I guess you would need a service layer of some sort to handle that logic before passing it to the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that custom [Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation) is right choice in your case.

First - update your entity to make it save its previous state (thanks to [@AlanHay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531056)):

```
@Entity
class ItemEntity {

    @Transient
    private ItemEntity previousState;

    @PostLoad
    private void setPreviousState(){
        previousState = new ItemEntity();
        //copy the fields
    }

    public ItemEntity getPreviousState(){
        return previousState;
    }
}
```

Then implement validator in which you check if the current user with some 'authority' has changed the fields:

```
public class ItemValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {   
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        SimpleGrantedAuthority userRole = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

        if (authorities.contains(userRole)) {

            ItemEntity item = (ItemEntity) target;
            prevItem = item.getPreviousState();

            String prevName = prevItem.getName();
            String prevCreator = prevItem.getCreator();
            String newName = item.getName();
            String newCreator = item.getCreator();

            if (!prevName.equals(newName)) {
                errors.rejectValue("name", "You cannot change Name field!");
            }

            if (!prevCreator.equals(newCreator)) {
                errors.rejectValue("creator", "You cannot change Creator field!");
            }
        }
        // Other checks...
    }
}
```

Then in `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` plug this Validator:

```
@Configuration
public class RepoRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
        v.addValidator("beforeCreate", itemValidator()); // POST (if needed)
        v.addValidator("beforeSave", itemValidator());   // PUT/PATCH
        super.configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(v);
    }

    @Bean
    ListingValidator itemValidator() {
        return new ItemValidator();
    }
}
```

I think this should work ...