# Get @PreUpdate value in @PostUpdate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I need to get the object value (*preUpdateOrder*) that was before saving (@PreUpdate), in the @PostUpdate.

For example, @PreUpdate the value of ***preUpdateOrder*** was 5, I need to get the value 5 when I am accessing ***preUpdateOrder*** in @PostUpdate, where ***postUpdateOrder*** is 6.

Here is my code,

```
public class AuditListener {

   private Order preUpdateOrder = new Order();
   private Order postUpdateOrder = new Order();

   @PreUpdate
   private void before(Object object) {
       if (object instanceof Order) {
           preUpdateOrder = ((Order) object);
       }
   }

   @PostUpdate
   private void after(Object object) {           
       if (object instanceof Order) {
           postUpdateOrder = ((Order) object);

           if(preUpdateOrder.getId().equals(postUpdateOrder.getId())){
               System.out.println("true");
           }
       }
   }
}



@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@Entity
public class Order{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get previouseState without fetching from the db using hibernate interceptor to create audit trail table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529208/how-to-get-previousestate-without-fetching-from-the-db-using-hibernate-intercept)

Answer (score 1):

JPA entity listeners are very limited. There is no way to get the old state.

You should use Hibernates interceptor functionality. It's easy to define an interceptor:

```
public static class LoggingInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(
        Object entity,
        Serializable id,
        Object[] currentState,
        Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames,
        Type[] types) {

       // use old and new state
    }
}
```

You then have to set the hibernate property in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=yourpackage.LoggingInterceptor
```

Please find more in the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events

Comment: I did in some other way, may be not that good, but working. I will share it in short time.