# Hibernate Interceptor incorrect mapped table data

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, interceptor

I have a ManyToMany mapping using a join table.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "access_management")
public class AccessMgmt
    extends CommonColumns
    implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "access_management_role_mapping",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "access_management_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id"))
@CsvBindByName(column = "roles")
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

When data is updated (onFlushDirty) previousState and currentState consist of the exact same data for the ManyToMany field (which is what should only be in currentState). I figure there is something going on with the join mapping table, because I don't have an entity for this table (access_management_role_mapping) its being updated and not hitting the interceptor, and then the parent object (access_management) is hitting the interceptor after the update. Just a suspicion, but its something like that because all the data is correct in the non-Audit Log tables.

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(
        final Object entity, final Serializable id,
        final Object[] currentState, final Object[] previousState,
        final String[] propertyNames, final Type[] types) {
... }
}
```

Second issue is that I really only want "parent" entities to hit the interceptor and have their previousState and currentState be "correct" object hit the custom interceptor. And by correct i mean to have the full object with the mappings in a previousState and currentState, the currentState has always been correct with the current setup. Currently tables with OneToMany Mappings have each Entity hit the interceptor individually which is fine-ish, but ultimately the parent object (the one the user had saved/edited) hits the interceptor last and has incorrect data for the previousState for any mapped fields (OneTo.. ManyTo.. ect)

I can add more of the code, but I figured most of it was unnecessary.

I think i can work around this by doing a few things.

1. Use envars... - (No thanks, would mean a full rewrite of this part.)
2. Change the ManyToMany to OneToMany and create the mapping table as an entity and handle it in the interceptor. (If I have too, but doesn't solve my second issue)
3. Add a transient of the parent object to save the previous state with a @PreLoad so I always have the previous state. (This fixes both issues, but seems like an odd thing todo, but what I will go with if someone here doesn't have a better idea.)([how to get previouseState without fetching from the db using hibernate interceptor to create audit trail table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529208/how-to-get-previousestate-without-fetching-from-the-db-using-hibernate-intercept))

UPDATE

Option 3 did not work how I expected and did not get the data I wanted at the time. So thats out.

I also tried using Hibernate Event Listeners instead of the interceptor with the same results.

Ultimately I might need to implement this without hibernate at all and do it at the Controller level.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your actual goal is. Do you just want to create an audit for the many to many table? You could create a copy of the set in a `@PostLoad` listener and use that state then in your interceptor.

Comment: Yea I essentially wrote my own auditing at this point because I didnt get an answer here. Instead of what you suggested currently I am handing it all in the controllers on the save of the specific data I want in the audit log and saving the full object so the mappings dont really affect it. This works for me, but is messier than using the.  hibernate interceptor way in my opinion and more prone to issues. I kept the hibernate interceptors to log to the log files just in case something goes wrong. Works for now, but was hoping for a better way possibly.

Comment: If you just want any audit log, you should really consider using Hibernate Envers. I don't see how that would need a full rewrite, it works on top of Hibernate Core.

Comment: Hibernate envars would work but doesn't really support mapped table data easily (i think I've used it in the past before). So either way i would need some custom solution for that. The goal is to show a delta on the screen for the user.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mapped table data" but it is absolutely possible to query all versions of an entity and compute/show the delta.

Comment: By mapped table i mean anything with a manyTo or OneTo AND entities using a mapping table which i thought was the term for atwo tables joined by a table with only id's that no entity exists for.

Comment: You mean a join/collection table? That's at least the term JPA uses for the many-to-many concept. Anyway, you can compute all of that with Envers if you like, but you will obviously have to learn how Envers works to do this. Still, Envers will solve many of your issues out of the box.