# Exclude some fields from audit with Spring Data JPA @LastModifiedDate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called User. This entity contains several fields and one of them is `lastModifiedDate`:

```
@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "last_modified_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
private ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate;
```

Every time the table is updated, this field gets updated too. Which per se is fine.
The issue is that in the same entity I have also another field called `loginTime`:

```
@Column(name = "login_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
private ZonedDateTime loginTime;
```

This field is updated whenever a new user logs into the application.
However, when users log in, since the `loginTime` field is updated, the field `lastModifiedDate` is also updated consequently.
Is there a way to prevent `lastModifiedDate` from being updated when specific fields (like `loginTime`) are updated?

Thank you

Comment: Not unless you rewrite the JPA listener that is involved in that and provide a way to exclude fields from there. From a JPA point-of-view the entity did change so what is wrong with that? It might be easier to move the `loginTime` to a new entity without a lastmodifieddate (just stick it into an table which keeps the login entires for instance).

Comment: The default behavior is the right behavior actually, still you want you can use `@PreUpdate` instead `@LastModifiedDate` and conditionally update Ex : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549023/4207306

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks in PreUpdate methods I have not access to the old and the new version. so I should implement logic in setters for each property. Not feasible.

Comment: I don't say you need to compare new to old, as you know early when you just want to update `loginTime` so restrict only that case either update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPQL update query using `@Query` to update only `loginTime` field then `lastModifiedDate` field will not be updated.

```
  @Modifying
  @Query("update User u set u.loginTime = :loginTime where u.id = :id")
  int updateLoginTime(@Param("loginTime") ZonedDateTime loginTime, @Param("id") Integer id);
```

Comment: Did you check the solution? Feel free to ask if you faced any problem.